# Null pointer returned to QML is true in conditional statements

Tags: c++, qt, null, qml, qvariant

Investigating a crash I found out that a non-`QObject` derived registered meta type always passes `if (obj)` checks even if it contains a `nullptr`.

Outputting the return value says `QVariant(Base*)` rather than `null`.

I suspect that `QVariant::isNull()` might be useful here:

> Returns true if this is a null variant, false otherwise. A variant is
>   considered null if it contains a default constructed value or a
>   built-in type instance that has an isNull method, in which case the
>   result would be the same as calling isNull on the wrapped object.

I assume that a `nullptr` should qualify for a "default constructed value" here, but it doesn't seem to be picked up by conditional statements in QML.

So maybe it is possible to implement that check via a free function? Or maybe I am looking at a bug here?

Update: It was deemed a [critical bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59744).

Comment: Or maybe the `QVariant` is explicitly constructed, given a `nullptr`? You could track back that value to its origin and check where it gets `nullptr` to see why you end up with null.

Comment: @Pixelchemist the conversion is implicit, it is converted by the QML engine. The value itself is unusable in QML, as it is neither a Q_OBEJCT nor a Q_GADGET, it is only assigned to pro properties or passed to C++ functions. And yes, the value is definitely a `nullptr` when returned, and even if it passes a check in JS, it is still a `nullptr` when sent back to the C++ side.

Comment: As of why it is null - that is intended, presupposing that a null pointer would fail a check on the JS side. The problem is that it is not treated as a null in JS.

Comment: Default-constructed zeros can't make a variant null. The doc probably says that a default-constructed `QVariant` is null. `assert(!QVariant(int{}).isNull());assert(QVariant{}.isNull());`

Comment: It says "default constructed value" not "default constructed variant". Default constructed values for Qt containers of type pointers are null pointers. I don't think expecting such a pointer to be evaluated as false in a JS conditional.